# How do I sort an array of objects using different arrays of objects?

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I'm having issues trying to get an array of objects to display in different order. We are supposed to have the output displayed names sorted out by index, first name, last name, and age. When I run the code I only get the names to display once. I've attached a picture of the desire output, I'm a little confused and blocked. Here is what I have so far:

```js
class Names {

  constructor(first, last, age) {
    this.first = first;
    this.last = last;
    this.age = age;
  }
}

function printObject(allNames, sortType, message) {
  if (sortType == "first") {
    allNames.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.first.localeCompare(b.first);
    });
  }

  if (sortType == "last") {
    allNames.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.last.localeCompare(b.last);
    });
  }

  if (sortType == "age") {
    allNames.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.age - b.age;
    });
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < allNames.length; i++) {
    console.log(message);
    console.log(allNames[i].first + " " + allNames[i].last + " " + allNames[i].age);
  }
}

// main fucntion 
function main() {
    var allNames = [];

    allNames.push(new Names("John", "Doe", 40));
    allNames.push(new Names("Jay", "Thrift", 30));
    allNames.push(new Names("Card", "Ace", 20));

    printObject(allNames, "age", "Message");
}

main();
```

[desire output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9O5G.png)

Comment: It is only displayed once because you are only calling the function once. Call it multiple times with different `sortType` to get multiple outputs.

Answer (score 1):

Are you just missing these lines to get all of the different sortings?

```
printObject(allNames, "first", "By first name");
printObject(allNames, "last", "By last name");
printObject(allNames, null, "By index");
```

Following `printObject(allNames, "age", "Message");`?

(Which I'd change to `printObject(allNames, "age", "By age");`)

Comment: Why would `allNames` need to be moved out of `main()`? It gets passed to the `printObject` function, so that part looks fine to me as is.